# R - assigning test (in ifelse) to be between two numbers for generating a dummy variable

Tags: r

Current code:

```
data$light <- ifelse(data$cigs == 1:5, 1, 0)
```

With the code above, I'm trying to focus on getting `ifelse` to only assign a `1` to values `1` through `5` in `cigs` (`cigs` being number of cigarettes smoked per day, ranging from `0` to `50`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `%in%`

```
data$light <- ifelse(data$cigs %in% c(1:5), 1, 0)
```

Or equivalently

```
data$light <- ifelse(data$cigs >=1& data$cigs <=5, 1, 0)
```

Comment: `ifelse` is not wrong, though it might be faster to do `1*(data$cigs %in% c(1:5))` or `as.integer(data$cigs %in% c(1:5))` (as long as all you're looking for are 1s and 0s).

Comment: J. Flink consider accepting the answer in that case